# Invalid time zone region while calling AT TIME ZONE function in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, timezone

Just a simple question about the "AT TIME ZONE" function in Oracle. It seems the time zone named CEST is not a valid argument for this function despite the fact it is listed in the view V$TIMEZONE_NAMES

```
select * from V$TIMEZONE_NAMES where tzname like '%Rome%';

TZNAME      TZABBREV CON_ID
----------- -------- ------
Europe/Rome LMT      0
Europe/Rome RMT      0
Europe/Rome CET      0
Europe/Rome CEST     0

SQL>
```

When I try to convert a timestamp to the time zone name CET, everything works as expected

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-MAG-24 02:00:00','RRRR-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AT TIME ZONE 'CET' "CET" 
FROM DUAL;

CET
--------------------------------
24-MAG-12 02:00:00,000000000 CET

SQL>
```

When I change the time zone to CEST, I get this error:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2012-MAG-24 02:00:00','RRRR-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AT TIME ZONE 'CEST' "CEST" 
  FROM DUAL;

ORA-01882: timezone region not found

SQL>
```

My question is: why is the CEST time zone NOT valid for this conversion?

For the sake of clarity I'm running an Oracle 12c instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AT TIME ZONE` takes a time zone *name* - you're passing in the time zone *abbreviation*. The names are in the `TZNAME` column of the results you're showing us, but you're using the value from `TZABBREV`. Abbreviations are a bad idea because:

- They're not unique, so can't act as identifiers.
- They only apply for *part* of the time... so in modern times, Europe/Rome varies between CET and CEST, as you can see from the table. If you've got to work out which abbreviation is actually in effect at a particular time, you might as well just specify the offset...

Basically, the answer is to use `'Europe/Rome'` instead of `'CET'`.

Comment: @OP: Quoting Jon: "CST is [used] three times. Once for Central Standard Time in the US – which is UTC-6. It’s also Central Standard Time in Australia – where it’s UTC+9.30. It’s also Central Summer Time in Australia, where it’s UTC+10.30. I think it takes a special kind of incompetence to use the same acronym in the same place for different offsets."

Comment: @Brian, when you do `SELECT distinct tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz WHERE tzabbrev = 'CST';` you get even eight zones.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Jon you must use the full time zone name instead of abbreviations, However, there are a few exceptions where you can also use the time zone abbreviations, that's the reason why `CET` worked.

```
SELECT tzabbrev, tzname, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
WHERE tzabbrev = tzname;

TZABBREV    TZNAME  TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)
CET CET +01:00
CST CST -06:00
EET EET +02:00
EST EST -05:00
GMT GMT +00:00
HST HST -10:00
MET MET +01:00
MST MST -07:00
PST PST -08:00
WET WET +00:00
```

Note. `'Europe/Rome'` is not the same as `'CET'`.
`'Europe/Rome'` automatically considers Daylight Saving Time, `'CET'` does not.